# Why unable to get related data in Self-referencing many-to-many in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I and new to django and working on a small application containing a model nameCustomUser.CustomUser is having ManyToMany relationship with itself, i have implemented feature, that a user can follow another user.But when i am trying to fetch all the users which current authenticated is following i am not getting the desired result.

**Models:-**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    user = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship', symmetrical=False, related_name='related_to')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'username']


    def get_all_followings(self):
        print("print {}".format(self))
        print("all followings {}".format(self.to_person))
    
class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='from_people', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='to_person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

***from_person*** means who is following, and ***to_person*** means to whome he is following.for example in my case *deep* is currently authenticated user, and he is following to *ram*.

So if i tried to print Relationship object i got following output:

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x00000273836034C0>, 'id': 1, 'from_person_id': 2, 'to_person_id': 4}
```

**view:-**

```
def see_all_followings(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        current_user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        all_followings = current_user.get_all_followings()
        # return render(request, "all_followings.html", {'users':, 'is_follow': True})
```

**OutPut which i got:-**

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
print deep@gmail.com
all followings user.Relationship.None  # But user is following one user..
```

Thanks in advance..
Hope to here from you soon..

Comment: @Willen Van Onsem i am getting the relationship object but i need all CustomUsers which currently authenticated user is following, how should i, can you please help..

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem i have undated the post please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve a manager, not the queryset, you need to use [**`.all()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all) to obtain the `QuerySet` the manager is managing, so:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # ⋮

    def get_all_followings(self):
        print(f'print {self}')
        print(f'all followings {self.to_person.all()}')
```

In your model you can specify the relation with:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # ⋮
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through='Relationship',
        through_fields=('from_person', 'to_person'),
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='related_to'
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'username']
```

Then you can access the follwers with:

```
current_user.following.all()
```

Comment: i am getting the relationship object but i need all CustomUsers which currently authenticated user is following, how should i, can you please help..

Comment: @Atharva: you use `current_user.user.all()` or `current_user.related_to.all()` depending on in which direction you define "following" (it is not clear what direction is "following" and what is "followed by", you might want to rename the name of the `ManyToManyField` and the `related_name`.)

Comment: ok wait i am undating the post.

Comment: i have undated the post please have a look.

Comment: @Atharva: please rename the `ManyToManyField`, it makes no sense to name this `user`, nor `related_to`, see updated answer.

Comment: OOOOO @Willem Van Onsem thanks i am having very problem in understand recursive relation ship thanks thanks a lot..